# PigPen Eclipse Setup

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having a super hard time setting up PigPen in Eclipse.  The official documentation is out-of-date (as far as I can find).

I got everything up and running (Eclipse, PigPen, Java, etc.) and can get to the point that I run a job, but I don't really know how to set up the configuration files, especially hadoop-site.xml and pig.configuration.  If anyone has gotten this to work and could post their general config files, I think that would be all I need.  This is my first attempt at using client tools on a Hadoop cluster.  All the other times I've worked directly on the cluster machines.

I'm on OSX if that makes any difference.  Sorry for not more specifics, I just am at a dead end and any documentation I find hasn't helped me yet.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Hadoop only runs on Linux based systems, so you should be fine if you're on OSX. The hadoop-site and pigconfiguration should be coming from the hadoop installation files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but almost a year later I found myself with this same issue. I happen to be using a 2.X version of Hadoop, but apparently Pig Pen hasn't caught up.

What I needed to do in my case was create a place holder for the depreciated `hadoop-site.xml` file before following all of the setup steps defined [here](https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigPen).

In my case, my `pig.properties` file was located here:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/pig-0.15.0/conf
```

At first I thought I could just make a link to an appropriate configuration, something like:

```
ln -s /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml /usr/local/hadoop/pig-0.15.0/conf/hadoop-site.xml
```

But the plugin couldn't handle a link and the configuration is quite different now (which I'll discuss below).

So I added a file named `hadoop-site.xml` to the above `conf` folder, and added a blank configuration to avoid parse errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="nutch-conf.xsl"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately if you don't add in the appropriate Hadoop configuration you lose the interactive goodness that is the whole point of Pig Pen, but with Hadoop 2.X being so different from Hadoop 1.X I didn't see a proper way to configure it (by all means comment if you find an appropriate configuration until they update Pig Pen). What you *do* get is the syntax highlighting, which I found useful for writing my Pig scripts.